# Unreachable Code - return startId;

Tags: java, android, return, unreachable-code

I'm attempting to add some functionality to my source code to log the fact at least one phone call has been made before I execute the rest of my code (which collects total amount of wifi and cell data usage and sends it via sms) however when I added the code to save the fact at least one phone call has been made I ended up with an error stating "Unreachable Code -  return startId;" and I'm not sure what is causing the issue.

Thanks in advance!

SOURCE GETTING ERROR: Unreachable Code -    return startId;

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
String text = "USR;1";
String ERROR = Constants.PREFS_NAME;
private Timer timer = new Timer();
private long period;
private long delay_interval;

public static final String swappedMdn(Context ctx) {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    // Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager instance
    String mdn = tm.getLine1Number();

    // Insure MDN is 10 characters
    if (mdn.length() < 10 || mdn == null)
        mdn = "0000000000";

    // Extract last 10 digits of MDN
    if (mdn.length() > 10)
        mdn = mdn.substring(mdn.length() - 10, mdn.length());
    char data[] = mdn.toCharArray();
    char digit;
    for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length()) % 2; index += 2) {
        digit = data[index];
        data[index] = data[index + 1];
        data[index + 1] = digit;

        Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DataCountService.class);

        SharedPreferences settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences(
                Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("0", new String(data));
        editor.commit();

    }

    return String.valueOf(data);

}

private Intent getIntent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId, int state,
        String incomingNumber) {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (intent == null) {

        // Exit gracefully if service not started by intent
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
    } else {

        if (extras != null) {

            if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
                // wait for phone to go offhook (probably set a boolean
                // flag) so you
                // know your app initiated the call.
                // Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");
                SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("callMade", "1");
                editor.commit();

            } else {

                // SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                // .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                // if (settings.getString("callsMade", "1").equals(1)) {

                String newMdn = swappedMdn(this);

                text = extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT);

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;1")) {

                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats
                            .getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

                    // get the date
                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "hh/mm/ss/MM/dd/yy");

                    String tag = ";";
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String DToDevice = s.format(new Date());
                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    String status = (settings.getString("status", "0"));
                    String info = String
                            .format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag + status + tag
                                    + settings.getString("0", newMdn) + tag
                                    + DToDevice + tag, mobileStr, totalStr
                                    + settings.getString("last_month", "0"));
                    info = "USI" + info.replace("USI", "");

                    // info = (info.replace("CN", "CO")).replace("WN",
                    // "WO");
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(info);
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("CN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("CN") + 2, "CO");
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("WN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("WN") + 2, "WO");
                    info = b.toString();

                    // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, info,
                                null, null);

                        // set status to enabled
                        Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("status", "1");
                        editor.commit();
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();

                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null, info,
                                null, null);
                    }
                }

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
            }
        } else if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                "//USR;0")) {

            // set status to disabled
            SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
            Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("status", "0");
            editor.commit();
            stopSelf();

        }
    }
    return START_STICKY;

    return startId;
}

private void StartActivity(android.content.Intent i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private Intent Intent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {

        period = Constants.PERIOD;
        delay_interval = Constants.DELAY_INTERVAL;

    } else {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        period = Constants.DEBUG_PERIOD;
        delay_interval = Constants.DEBUG_DELAY_INTERVAL;
    }
    startServiceTimer();
}

private void startServiceTimer() {
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                    .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
            if (settings.getString("status", "0").equals(1)) {

                // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                totalBytes /= 1000000;
                mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                String tag = ";";
                String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                String info = String.format("CO%s,WO%s", tag, mobileStr,
                        totalStr);

                // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences
                SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                editor.putString("last_month", info);
                editor.commit();

                // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data usage)
                // and save the current time
                String sms = "";
                sms += ("CO" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                        .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);
                sms += ("WO" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                        + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                        .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                        .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);

                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                    String shortCode = settings.getString(
                            Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                            Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null,
                            sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                            null);
                    editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                            System.currentTimeMillis());
                    editor.commit();
                } else {
                    SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                            Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                            sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                            null);
                }

            }
        }
    }, delay_interval, period);

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return null;

}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return super.onUnbind(intent);

}
```

}

SOURCE BEFORE THE NEW CODE / ERROR (WORKS FINE):

```
  public class DataCountService extends Service {
        String text = "USR;1";
        String ERROR = Constants.PREFS_NAME;
        private Timer timer = new Timer();
        private long period;
        private long delay_interval;

    public static final String swappedMdn(Context ctx) {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        // Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager instance
        String mdn = tm.getLine1Number();

        // Insure MDN is 10 characters
        if (mdn.length() < 10 || mdn == null)
            mdn = "0000000000";

        // Extract last 10 digits of MDN
        if (mdn.length() > 10)
            mdn = mdn.substring(mdn.length() - 10, mdn.length());
        char data[] = mdn.toCharArray();
        char digit;
        for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length()) % 2; index += 2) {
            digit = data[index];
            data[index] = data[index + 1];
            data[index + 1] = digit;

             Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DataCountService.class);


                SharedPreferences settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("0", new String(data));
                editor.commit(); 

        }

        return String.valueOf(data);

    }


    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");


        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if (intent == null) {

            // Exit gracefully if service not started by intent
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
        } else {

            if (extras != null) {

                String newMdn = swappedMdn(this);

                text = extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT);

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                        "//USR;1")) {

                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");


                    // get the date
                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "hh/mm/ss/MM/dd/yy");
                    SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    String tag = ";";


                    //String mdn = extras.getString(DataCountUtilities.swappedMdn(this));
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String DToDevice = s.format(new Date());
                    String status = (settings.getString("status", "0"));
                    String info = String.format("USI%sCN%s,WN%s", tag + status
                            + tag + settings.getString("0", newMdn) + tag + DToDevice + tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr + settings.getString("last_month", "0"));
                    info = "USI" + info.replace("USI", "");

                    // info = (info.replace("CN", "CO")).replace("WN", "WO");
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(info);
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("CN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("CN") + 2, "CO");
                    b.replace(info.lastIndexOf("WN") - 1,
                            info.lastIndexOf("WN") + 2, "WO");
                    info = b.toString();

                    // send traffic info via sms & save the current time
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null, info, null,
                                null);

                        // set status to enabled
                        Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString("status", "1");
                        editor.commit();
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();

                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null, info, null,
                                null);
                    }
                }

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable                
            } else if (extras.getString(Constants.DM_SMS_CONTENT).contains(
                    "//USR;0")) {

                // set status to disabled
                SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("status", "0");
                editor.commit();
                stopSelf();


            }

            return START_STICKY;
        }
        return startId;
    }

    private void StartActivity(android.content.Intent i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private Intent Intent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {

            period = Constants.PERIOD;
            delay_interval = Constants.DELAY_INTERVAL;

        } else {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            period = Constants.DEBUG_PERIOD;
            delay_interval = Constants.DEBUG_DELAY_INTERVAL;
        }
        startServiceTimer();
    }

    private void startServiceTimer() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                if (settings.getString("status", "0").equals(1)) {

                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                    String tag = ";";
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String info = String.format("CO%s,WO%s", tag, mobileStr,
                            totalStr);

                    // save Network and Wifi data in sharedPreferences
                    SharedPreferences cnwn = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, 0);
                    Editor editor = cnwn.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_month", info);
                    editor.commit();


                    // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data usage) and save the current time                 
                    String sms = "";
                    sms += ("CO" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);
                    sms += ("WO" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                            .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    if (Config.DEVELOPMENT) {
                        String shortCode = settings.getString(
                                Constants.PREFS_KEY_SHORT_CODE,
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE);
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(shortCode, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                                null);
                        editor.putLong("smstimestamp",
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
                        editor.commit();
                    } else {
                        SmsManager ackSMS = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
                                Constants.DEFAULT_SHORT_CODE, null,
                                sms + cnwn.getString("last_month", ""), null,
                                null);
                    }

                }
            }
        }, delay_interval, period);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

    }
```

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: you already have this  `return START_STICKY` so it will not reach the next statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just keep one `return` in

```
return START_STICKY;

return startId;
```

Comment: Would it be more wise to keep return START_STICKY (since it's the one that is necessary to get the service going?)

Answer (score 6):

Well yes, look at this code:

```
return START_STICKY;

return startId;
```

How do you ever expect to get to the second statement? Which value do you *actually* want to return? Remove the statement you don't want.

This is a great example of where the compiler is really saving you from yourself - your code doesn't make sense, so it's helpful for the compiler to stop you from running this code.

You should also take a step back and work out why you weren't able to diagnose this yourself:

- Did you understand the error message?
- Did you carefully examine the code in question?
- Did you try to work out how execution *could* reach that unreachable code?

It's always a good idea to try to learn from this sort of thing. If you're unfamiliar with reachability, look at the [JLS section 14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21).

Answer (score 0):

You can not return multiple times. If you return a value that will end the method... So the next return will not be executed..

```
return START_STICKY;  // at this line method will be exited

return startId;  // this will never executed
```